# Loading data in Hadoop with spring xd

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hdfs, spring-xd

I am trying to create a stream between an HTTP source and HDFS sink. My springXD and HDFS are installed on different machines** but I am able to fire the `hadoop fs ls /` command successfully.

After creating and deploying stream, when I post data using:

```
http post --target http://{ipaddressofhdfsmachine:8020} -- data"hello"
```

It is throwing the error:

> failed to send data to http end point http://{ipaddressofhdfsmachine:8020}

When I used `localhost with port 9000` it completed successfully but nothing showed up in hdfs.

Is it necessary to have hdfs and spring on same machine to create stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little difficult to know what's wrong but I'll try to make an educated guess. I don't know if you're running XD singlenode or distributed mode, did you change a default configuration and how did you create a stream. Reference doc can be found from [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/)

I'm my setup I'm running XD on my main OS(localhost) and HDFS on my vm(node1).

Because on default hdfs namenode address is assumed to be hdfs://localhost:8020 it needs to be changed. For this use `servers.yml` file and change `fsUri` (pay attention to spaces in this yaml file format).

`config/servers.yml`:

```
# Hadoop properties
spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://node1:8020
```

I start XD single node:

```
./xd-singlenode
```

Then run stream commands, write something and check what got written:

```
xd:>hadoop config fs --namenode hdfs://node1:8020

xd:>hadoop fs ls --recursive true --dir /xd
lsr: `/xd': No such file or directory

xd:>stream create --name test --definition "http|hdfs" --deploy
Created and deployed new stream 'test'

xd:>http post --data "hello" http://localhost:9000
> POST (text/plain;Charset=UTF-8) http://localhost:9000 hello
> 200 OK

xd:>hadoop fs ls --recursive true --dir /xd
drwxr-xr-x   - jvalkealahti supergroup          0 2014-07-14 21:33 /xd/test
-rw-r--r--   3 jvalkealahti supergroup          0 2014-07-14 21:33 /xd/test/test-0.txt.tmp

xd:>stream destroy --name test 
Destroyed stream 'test'

xd:>hadoop fs ls --recursive true --dir /xd
drwxr-xr-x   - jvalkealahti supergroup          0 2014-07-14 21:33 /xd/test
-rw-r--r--   3 jvalkealahti supergroup          6 2014-07-14 21:33 /xd/test/test-0.txt

xd:>hadoop fs cat --path /xd/test/test-0.txt
hello
```

Comment: Thanks Janne for answering. I did what you suggested but come up with same result. I posted data successfully using **http post** but when I did hadoop fs -ls recursive true --dir /xd it gave:lsr:DEPRECATED :Please use 'ls-R' instead.& lsr: '/xd' no such file or directory.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure logs for XD singlenode should show some errors. If you ran it with singlenode then XD admin/container is executed within a same jvm so you'd see logging for admin/container is a same shell.

Comment: I'd double check the spring.hadoop.fsUri setting in servers.yml. Yaml format is really sensitive for correct indentation and usage of spaces not tabs. Anyway if you made mistake there or if something else went wrong, logs should show if hdfs sink is unable to write to hdfs.

Comment: One other problem I've seen is that on default hdfs sink tries to write into a /xd/<streamname>. If sink doesn't have permissions to create this directory, then you can change it using a --directory config option.

Comment: Hey Janne, I checked the logs and encountered with an error MessageDeliveryException saying Dispatcher has no subscribers. Any suggesstions on that.I am trying to fix it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post to your XD machine, not your Hadoop HDFS machine.

The XD HTTP receiver will get the POST and route it to HDFS for you.

Make sure you node is setup for your Hadoop and your shell is too.

if you are using Pivotal PHD 2.0 for example:

```
xd-singlenode --hadoopDistro phd20

xd-shell --hadoopDistro phd20

xd:> had config fs --namenode hdfs://MyPivotalHDServer:8020
```

Check out Spring-XD's Github Documentation for the latest and get the current Spring XD, which is constantly getting better.   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Sources#http

To create a stream definition in the server using the XD shell

```
xd:> stream create --name httptest --definition "http | hdfs" --deploy
```

Post some data to the http server on the default port of 9000

```
xd:> http post --target http://localhost:9000 --data "hello world to hadoop from springxd"
```

This youtube video will walk you through an example:  http://youtu.be/41sIhawjHE0?t=37m6s

You have to post a few times, depending on when your file will get full enough to roll over into a new chunk, or you need to stop the stream to check the file.

Send things to log first so you can see it in the XD output logs.   Good for debugging.

Comment: make sure you create your main /xd directory and give it proper permissions usually 777 for testing to make sure everything is good and test it from regular HDFS and from XD commands to HDFS.